# Nagios is active on CLI but not running on Web Interface

Tags: nagios

Good morning,

I have a problem with my Nagios configuration. This is the response of service nagios status :

```
    root@SRV-SUPERVISION-BT:~# service nagios status
● nagios.service - LSB: Starts and stops the Nagios monitoring server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/nagios)
   Active: active (running) since ven. 2016-06-17 09:47:46 CEST; 41min ago
  Process: 458 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/nagios start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nagios.service
           ├─533 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -d /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios...
           ├─553 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios --worker /usr/local/nagios/var/...
           ├─555 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios --worker /usr/local/nagios/var/...
           ├─556 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios --worker /usr/local/nagios/var/...
           ├─558 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios --worker /usr/local/nagios/var/...
           ├─559 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios --worker /usr/local/nagios/var/...
           ├─560 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios --worker /usr/local/nagios/var/...
           └─623 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -d /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios...

juin 17 09:47:46 SRV-SUPERVISION-BT nagios[533]: nerd: Channel opathchecks r...y
juin 17 09:47:46 SRV-SUPERVISION-BT nagios[533]: nerd: Fully initialized and...!
juin 17 09:47:46 SRV-SUPERVISION-BT nagios[533]: wproc: Successfully registe...r
juin 17 09:47:46 SRV-SUPERVISION-BT nagios[533]: wproc: Registry request: na...3
juin 17 09:47:46 SRV-SUPERVISION-BT nagios[533]: wproc: Registry request: na...8
juin 17 09:47:46 SRV-SUPERVISION-BT nagios[533]: wproc: Registry request: na...9
juin 17 09:47:46 SRV-SUPERVISION-BT nagios[533]: wproc: Registry request: na...6
juin 17 09:47:46 SRV-SUPERVISION-BT nagios[533]: wproc: Registry request: na...0
juin 17 09:47:46 SRV-SUPERVISION-BT nagios[533]: wproc: Registry request: na...5
juin 17 09:47:48 SRV-SUPERVISION-BT nagios[533]: Successfully launched comma...3
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

But when I'm going on the web interface, Nagios Core is not running.

[image: Nagios Web interface not running screenshot]

The configtest command is also right :

```
root@SRV-SUPERVISION-BT:~# service nagios configtest

Nagios Core 4.1.1
Copyright (c) 2009-present Nagios Core Development Team and Community Contributors
Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Ethan Galstad
Last Modified: 08-19-2015
License: GPL

Website: https://www.nagios.org
Reading configuration data...
   Read main config file okay...
   Read object config files okay...

Running pre-flight check on configuration data...

Checking objects...
    Checked 8 services.
    Checked 1 hosts.
    Checked 1 host groups.
    Checked 0 service groups.
    Checked 1 contacts.
    Checked 1 contact groups.
    Checked 24 commands.
    Checked 5 time periods.
    Checked 0 host escalations.
    Checked 0 service escalations.
Checking for circular paths...
    Checked 1 hosts
    Checked 0 service dependencies
    Checked 0 host dependencies
    Checked 5 timeperiods
Checking global event handlers...
Checking obsessive compulsive processor commands...
Checking misc settings...

Total Warnings: 0
Total Errors:   0

Things look okay - No serious problems were detected during the pre-flight check
Object precache file created:
/usr/local/nagios/var/objects.precache
```

Also, this is the right of my /usr/local/nagios/var:

```
root@SRV-SUPERVISION-BT:/usr/local/nagios/bin# ls /usr/local/nagios/var -l
total 88
drwxrwsr-x 2 nagios nagios  4096 juin  16 23:59 archives
-rw-r--r-- 1 nagios nagios    34 juin  17 11:00 nagios.configtest
-rw-r--r-- 1 nagios nagios     4 juin  17 09:47 nagios.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 nagios nagios  3007 juin  17 10:47 nagios.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 nagios nagios 12665 juin  17 09:47 objects.cache
-rw-r--r-- 1 nagios nagios 12665 juin  17 11:00 objects.precache
-rw------- 1 nagios nagios 13062 juin  17 10:47 retention.dat
drwxrwsr-x 2 nagios nagcmd  4096 juin  17 09:47 rw
drwxr-sr-x 3 root   nagios  4096 juin   3 08:28 spool
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nagios nagios 13485 juin  17 11:26 status.dat
```

I'm on Debian :

```
    root@SRV-SUPERVISION-BT:~# uname -a
Linux SRV-SUPERVISION-BT 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2 (2016-04-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I do not understand the problem. If anyone can help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

First you must install fcgiwrap:

[image]

Depending on your distribution you should use your package manager.

Then, you should enable cgi module in your Web Server, for examle, in apache:

[image]

Finally, restart apache and it´s should be work.

Answer (score 0):

You must install/run `fcgiwrap` and use it in your web-server `apache/nginx/..`